# I can't get images to work without the entire file root

Tags: html, css, image

hope you can help. I've written many pages for sites before (only mock up ones for my own practicing) but with my new (old but runs windows 10) laptop for some reason images wont load without using the entire file path. e.g C:\Users\theap\OneDrive\Desktop\images/dogs.jpg  the image file is on my desktop labeled images. the all images end with .jpg  so i type  but only the alt shows with alt view in browser. I've never encountered this before. I've tried all different images, extentions and paths. the only way they load is in css using background-image: ../images/dogs.jpg
Using this path doesn't work in the html page. I am doing a web development course and have sent them screenshots of my code and everything I've tried but they didn't seem overly interested in helping. I have been trying to sort this for nearly a month now, petrol and matches seems to be my next option. Does anyone have any solutions? Please? anyone at all???

I have tried all I can think of, all youtube videos and google searches just show how to upload images, not trouble shoot this particular problem. I'm wondering if maybe it's a setting on my computer?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  Nobody can tell you what's wrong with code we can't see.  Please provide a [mcve] demonstrating the problem.  To learn more about this community and how we can help you, please start with the [tour] and read [ask] and its linked resources.

Comment: Additionally, this sounds suspect... *"e.g C:\Users\theap\OneDrive\Desktop\images/dogs.jpg the image file is on my desktop labeled images"* - If you're doing web development, **ideally** that would involve serving the page from a web server (even one running locally on your workstation), not just opening an HTML file from your file system.  The latter still works, but has quirks and limitations when it comes to web development.

Comment: Single file vs a "web page" served from a local web server seems to be in play here but we can only speculate...

Comment: Thanks for the replys. So I only started my course in January with this laptop but while writting code before on other laptops I never had an issue. In my html page when I save and opt to open in a default browser the page layout would be as you  would expect, including any images put into the code. Code I've used before is <img src="images/dog.jpg"> This would load the required image from the folder named images from my desktop, that's the only file path that was needed. But now it will only load an image if I copy or type the entire file path to my hard drive. I'm baffled lol.

Answer (score 0):

It won't load because you entered the wrong address... I tried when I entered the address of the system, the image was not displayed, but when I entered the address of the local browser, the image was displayed.

I guess this addressing is wrong :

```
c:\Users\theap\OneDrive\Desktop\images/dogs.jpg
```

This address is correct :

```
https://localhost/path/to/myimage
```